# XSLT sort data in variable and save them to another variable

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a problem. I have the following XML

```
<countryList> 
   <country>
      <name>Afghanistan</name>
      <population>29117000</population>
      <area>654329</area>
   </country>
   <country>
      <name>Albania</name>
      <population>3195000</population>
      <area>28748</area>
   </country>
   <country>
      <name>Algeria</name>
      <population>35423000</population>
      <area>2381741</area>
   </country>
   <country>
      <name>Andorra</name>
      <population>84082</population>
      <area>468</area>
   </country>
</countryList>
```

I have one question. All I need to do is divide population/area and sort these divisions for each country. However, I tried this

```
<xsl:variable name="Podiel">
        <xsl:value-of select="../population div ../area"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="PodielPodiel">
        <xsl:for-each select="$Podiel">
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
```

but I still get error

```
The 'select' expression does not evaluate to a node set.
no result for data1.xml
```

Any help? I just want to know the maximum of all divisions.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a larger scope of your code would help us understand. But it looks like you may not be calculating your `$Podiel` variable with the correct path to those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether the issue has been resolved, however for using `node-set` in XSLT 1.0, extension functions have to be used. Please refer to [node-set extension](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) for additional details on it's usage in XSLT 1.0.

If at all the `country` list in the input XML needs to be sorted on the value of `population div area`, the `number()` function can be used within `<xsl:sort>`. Declaring variables and calculating the additional values and then accessing the variable is not required.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > 
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="countryList">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="country">
                <xsl:sort select="number(population div area)" data-type="number" order="descending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<countryList>
    <country>
        <name>Andorra</name>
        <population>84082</population>
        <area>468</area>
    </country>
    <country>
        <name>Albania</name>
        <population>3195000</population>
        <area>28748</area>
    </country>
    <country>
        <name>Afghanistan</name>
        <population>29117000</population>
        <area>654329</area>
    </country>
    <country>
        <name>Algeria</name>
        <population>35423000</population>
        <area>2381741</area>
    </country>
</countryList>
```